# How do I get key based on some specific condition from values in a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I want a specific key from the HashMap based on a specific condition for the values. For example:
My HashMap is of the type `<String,Integer>`.

```
Map<String,Integer> getValuesInMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
Output = {Python=1, Java=1, OOPS=2, language=1, Ruby=3, Hey=1}
```

I want to retrieve the keys from this map where the integer count (i.e. value) is more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well `HashMap` is not made for this kind of operations, so you can either do manually, or use `Stream`:

```
getValuesInMap.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(e -> e.getValue() >  1)
  .map(e -> e.getKey())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java greater than `1.7`, you can use `streams` for that as shown below

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Python", 1);
    map.put("Java", 1);
    map.put("OOPS", 2);
    map.put("Language", 1);
    map.put("Ruby", 3);
    map.put("Hey", 1);

    List<String> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collection.removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) on the map’s values:

```
getValuesInMap.values().removeIf(count -> count <= 0);
System.out.println(getValuesInMap);
```

Be aware that the above will actually remove entries from your Map.  If you need to preserve the original Map, make a copy:

```
Map<String, Integer> copy = new LinkedHashMap<>(getValuesInMap);
copy.values().removeIf(count -> count <= 0);
System.out.println(copy);
```